# "--noprofile" or "--norc" functionality in zsh?

Tags: zsh

Short and sweet: Is there a way to accomplish what **--noprofile** and **--norc** bash switches do using zsh?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
zsh -f
zsh --no-rcs
```

The system-wide `zshenv` file (usually `/etc/zshenv` or `/etc/zsh/zshenv` or `/usr/local/lib/zsh/zshenv`) is always read, the only way to avoid this is to edit the zsh binary or patch the source.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! I'm using zsh for shell, and when I start BitNami cloud tools, it opens a new shell.  Since it's the user .zshrc that causes some trouble, --no-rcs will take care of that.